# how to display pick list values on top in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components

I have a combobox in LWC in tbody of a manual table

but instead of showing options at the top it adds a vertical scroll in that area to see options only scrolling on that area as shown in below image:

[image]
There is plenty of space on the page but still instead of showing values at top it adds vertical scroll bar, I have tried fixing its position and with increasing  the z-index but still no luck, please suggest.

I have created a playground [Playground](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/ndaRgMaD/2/edit) and once you click on the picklist then instead of showing the values on top it will add a vertical scroll bar at the side

Comment: We'd need to see some example code to replicate the issue. Would it be possible to create a [short, self-contained, compilable example](http://sscce.org/) for us to look at?

Comment: Thank you for responding, I have updated my question.

Comment: @sfdcfox I have added a playground in my question and once you click on the pick list you wont see the expected behavior

Comment: You didn't have enough of an example, so I [edited](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/ndaRgMaD/4/edit)... it looks like it's working, at least in my browser.

Comment: my deep apologies, the above playground has the previous data may be I forgot to save, anyways  the problem I was facing because of   a div tag on table "overflow:auto", I removed the same and everything is working as expected, thank you so much for your kind help and sorry again for the outdated data in playground.